# display permission for all files that start with -

Tags: permissions, ls, command

I need to display the permissions details for all the files names in a directory that begin with just "_".
I have tried various commands using ls and find and no joy.

Comment: Do the filenames start with dash or the `ls` permissions string?

Comment: Sorry its an underscore, the file names that start with an underscore

Comment: Sorry for the mis-edit, then! You had an underscore in the title, but a dash in the body. Feel free to edit the question to take it in the correct direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
ls -l -- -*
```

The -- indicates that what follows are not command line options.

Based on your update, for underscores you should just be able to do:

```
ls -l _*
```

Though the -- option won't hurt (it just won't do anything in that case)

Comment: yes i used _ as i noticed the dash. worked perfectly

Answer (score 4):

"-" is interpreted as a parameter, but you don't need to suffer, just append the path before the file name or just use ./.

```
touch ./-badfilename1 ./-badfilename2
ls -l ./-* 
ls -l /full/path/for/the/file/-* 
rm ./-badfilename?
```

And every command will just work (ls, rm, cat, touch etc!).